# YSlow tells me site is not compressed even though it is

Tags: apache, compression, yslow, mod-deflate

"Grade F on Compress components with gzip

There are 19 plain text components that should be sent compressed"

I have checked the compression of the main page, as well as all 19 components individually using "http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/" and it shows compression in all of them. Furthermore, I ensured I'm not using a proxy and that "Accepting-Encoding" is gzip/deflate using "http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test". Contrary to these results, the mod_deflate log files is as follows (excerpt):

> ... "GET / HTTP/1.1" 4498/13306 (33%)
>   "GET /Home_Page/style.css HTTP/1.1"
>   -/- (-%) "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%) "GET /css/slimbox.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%) "GET
>   /js/validator_o.js HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
>   ...

So it's not compressing the css or js files? My config file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/javascript text/xml image/svg+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/atom_xml application/rss+xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/x-httpd-php application/x-httpd-fastphp

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.avi$ no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mov$ no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp4$ no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.rm$ no-gzip dont-vary

   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    DeflateFilterNote Input instream
    DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
    DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio
    LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
    CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/deflate_log deflate </IfModule>
```

Firefox 3.6.8
Windows 7 Professional
ISP: Rogers

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it worked now. I set the modified the config file as follows

```
# Method 2: Compress all content, manually excluding specified file types
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # place filter 'DEFLATE' on all outgoing content
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  # exclude uncompressible content via file type
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip)$ no-gzip
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # properly handle requests coming from behind proxies
    Header append Vary User-Agent
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Then did a browser cache reload and checked the log files and it was compressed. Yslow agreed.